# Is the formula below for $S(n,k)$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> $$S(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i^n(-1)^{k-i}}{(k-i)!(i-1)!}$$
>   Calculate $S(5,3)$ by using this formula and by listing all possible partitions of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ into $3$ blocks. Are they the same?

By the formula I got $S(5,3)=90$ Now how am I going to list this number of partitions?  And next it says correct the formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simplifying the formula
\begin{eqnarray*}
S(n,k) =\frac{1}{k!} \sum_{i=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-i} \binom{k}{i} i^n
\end{eqnarray*}
you have probably bumped $n$ down by one. The value $S(6,3)=90$ is correct, try looking at the partitions of $[6]$ into $3$ blocks.

Comment: No, it asks for $S(5,3)$

Comment: $S(5,3)=25$ ... you need $i^{n-1}$ in your formula

Comment: Do you mean multiplying by $i^{n-1}$ or something else?

Comment: No, that's right, you cancelled a factor of $i$ between $i^n$ and $i!$.

Comment: I think this is the correct version: $S(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i^{n-1}(-1)^{k-i}}{(k-i)!(i-1)!}$ or equivalently : $S(n,k)=\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{i^{n}(-1)^{k-i}}{(k-i)!(i)!}$

Comment: Yes, I agree with your formula now $\ddot \smile$